I get CS1503 error after calling a function from another form in c#
I wrote the following to call my function in Form4 in Form5.
public partial class Form5 : Form
{
    private Form4 _form4;

    public Form5(Form4 form4)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _form4 = form4;
    }
}

With this I managed to call my function like this:
_form4.numOfRows()

But this time it started giving error CS1503 in the following part of Form3:
private void btnExam_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form5 exam = new Form5(this);
    exam.Show();
    this.Hide();
}

It says:

Error CS1503
Argument 1: Cannot convert from 'Project.Form3' to 'Project.Form4'

I would be very grateful if someone could help me with this.

The constructor of Form5 expects an instance of type Form4 - so you of course can't just construct a new Form5 and pass in an object of type Form3  instead .....

@marc_s So what can I do to switch between forms instead?

@Harun it's not clear what eactly you are trying to do. Please post a [mre]. If you'd like Form5 to hold any other form (not just a Form4), you can change the _form4 member to something like Form _form (and also change the parameter of the Form5 constructor accordingly).

The correct way to do this depends on information that you have not provided. What is the relationship among the three forms? Which creates which and how and when are they each displayed? You may well need to change a number of things to do what you want properly. The fact that your forms still have the default names is not encouraging, as all forms and controls should be renamed when created, so the name makes it plain what they are actually for.

Something that doesn't directly influence the UI should be put into a class of its own - then you can instantiate and use that class from different forms, without having to get references from one form to another ...

Please cease accepting the default name for every form you create and give them a sensible name that more aptly describes their purpose instead: LoginForm, MainForm, SettingsForm, NewUserForm. Same for any controls (_usernameLabel, not label27 etc)

In your example, this is a reference to Form3, not to Form4. Create a Form4 object and use it instead.
